# Scrutinizer: build and test in a subdirectory

Tags: php, composer-php, phpspec, scrutinizer

I have a repo with both front and backend application and i want to use scrutinizer to build and test my backend (PHP) application.
How can i tell (or configure) scrutinizer to build and test my application in this subdirectory?

Here is the basic structure of my repo:

```
root
|__Api
|  |_src
|  |_composer.json
|  |_phpspec.yml
|  |_ ...
|
|__Front
   |_index.html
   |_api.php
   |_ ...
```

I would like to run `composer install` and phpspec in the Api directory.

Thank you,
JM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the directory in your `.scrutinizer.yml`:

```
build:
    project_setup:
        before:
            - "cd Api"
```

https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/configuration/build#dependencies-project-setup

If you want to exclude frontend files from analysis, filter them out, e.g:

```
filter:
    paths: [Api/src/*]
```

https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/reviews/excluding_files_from_analysis

Comment: thx a lot. I didn't think to `project_setup`. I tried `environment` but i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me

```
build:
    root_path: 'app/'
```

But `project_setup` did not work for me.